# How to get logged in user information in Microsoft teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am new in teams development. Is there any way to get the logged in user information like user full name, the number associated with his team account and other user details?

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a bot, then you can get the current user AADId and display name using turnContext.Activity.From.AadObjectId and turnContext.Activity.From.Name.

If you are building a tab, then you can get the id & userPrincipalName from [Tab Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context?tabs=Json-v2%2Cteamsjs-v2).

Then you can use Graph API to get user details. You need to pass the id or userPrincipalName - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Additional reference to get bot context - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet#get-single-member-details